# c# backgroundworker with a running class

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I want to start a background worker from a form.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        ExtClass.doit("Hello", "World");
    }
```

Background worker inserts "Hello World" in the text box.

```
    public static void doit(string a, string b)
    {
        Form F1 = Application.openForms[0] as Form1;
        F1.textbox1.Text = a + b;
    }
```

But i get an Exception.
How can i access a form control from the background worker?

Answer (score 2):

The background worker does the work in the backgrounnd (as the name implies).

All `Control` objects are designed to **not** be thread safe.  You can only access them from the thread that created them (usually called the UI thread).

While there are ways of executing a block of code in the UI thread, you should take a fundamental look at your design first.  The idea of using a background worker is to do work in the background; work that does *not* involve interaction with the user interface.

If you need to get information from the UI to do the work, you should get it before starting the background worker and pass the information in as arguments to the work method.  If you want to update the UI with the results of the operation you should use the completed event handler. (Which will always run in the UI thread; the BGW class takes care of that for you.)  If you need to update a progress bar or label with progress, you should use the progress updated event and call update progress on the BGW.  The progress updated event also runs in the UI thread.

Comment: hi, 
found some information about Invoke Method but dont know how to use exactly in my constellation.
but i need the background to do some checks for the User like retrieve information about files or some remote server. and dont want that the UI is freeze.

Comment: @FrankFischer And I'm telling you that you probably shouldn't.  The entire point of using a background worker is that it will simplify interactions between a background and UI thread so that you don't *need* to use `Invoke`.  Are there times where it's useful or even needed, sure, is this one of them, probably not.

Comment: @FrankFischer Regarding your edit, the idea is that all of the non-UI related tasks should go in the DoWork event handler, and none of the UI updating.  You should then set the `Result` to be whatever the results of the processing are, and then access that result in the completed event handler.  That completed event handler (which runs in the UI thread) is where you should update the controls with the results of the long running operation.

Comment: so i do all work and transfer my class into the Backgroundworker to do the work and set the UI Controls. ?

Edit: ok my class connects to a exchange server and get all directorys the directorys are insert to the checkedlistbox by databinding. 
iwant to to this by external thread because the connection tooks some seconds and then the UI is freeze while the UI is connecting to  exchange Server

Comment: @FrankFischer If you want to have an entirely external class that does work that's just fine, but it shouldn't touch any of the controls at all.  All of the logic for actually interacting with a form's controls should be in that form's definition.  `ExtClass.doit` should just return some value, rather than updating the UI with the result, and the form class should then store the value that it returns and use it in the completed event of the background worker to update the UI.

Comment: ok then my class kann do some work, and only send back the result 
the backgroundWorker RunWorkerCompleted
take the results and change the ui controls right?

Comment: @FrankFischer Correct.  There are examples of this on the MSDN page for BackgroundWorker, and also in lots of places all over the web if you are having trouble.  If you can't get it after looking around for a bit you'll need to post more of what you have for me to give more detail than I already have.

Comment: thank you Servy i will look and if some problems comes up i
come back to you.

my plan is:
get the folders from a user from exchange Server,
this does my class, my class also change the UI entrys in checkedlistbox and add all Folder Names and IDs to it.

but i want to do this in a background thread because the connect to server and getting the folders and fill the table takes some seconds in this time the UI freezes

Answer (score 1):

```
F1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(()=> { F1.textbox1.Text = a + b; }));
```

Comment: Why start a background worker just to invoke back to the UI thread?

Comment: For example: reading data from FS or other long operation, before change UI

Comment: FS?  What does that stand for?  As I've said in my answer, there are 3 common use cases.  You either need info from controls to do the long running task, in which case access them before starting the background worker and pass the information in, you need to update controls with progress, in which case use the BGW's progress reporting methods/events, or you need to update the UI with the results, in which case you use the completed event.  Are there other edge cases, sure, but they're just that, edge cases, and not the norm.

Comment: no, the class connect to exchange server and the class is filling a datatable that is bind to checkedlistbox and fill it and the connect tooks some second ... while UI is freeze

Comment: so when i understand,starting the backgroundworker this runns my class => my class do some work get the folders from exchange oder other dings an return data
the data retured i processing next with the RunWorkerCompleted
and fill textboxes or tables

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a reference back to the Form and use either the Invoke or Begin/End Invoke passing in the method that modifies the Form.

To hold the reference I suggest you use The [RunWorkerAsync(Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f00zz5b2.aspx) passing the control and get the reference via the DoWork Arg's [Argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.doworkeventargs.argument.aspx).

Comment: the background do work start the ohter class,
the class sends only all the values back, and the RunWorkerCompleted get the values from dowork and change the ui?

Comment: You could use the completed method or you could just do it in the DoWork. So it would be Run -> Call what ever operation then call the form update -> Run Completed Event fires.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve the problem, you should create `Form1` reference instead of the reference to the `Form` because `Form` doesn't have `textBox1` field but your `Form1` does and this is the source of the Exception, you should change this:

```
Form F1 = Application.OpenForms[0] as Form1;
```

into this

```
Form1 F1 = Application.OpenForms[0] as Form1;
```

and then you should Invoke the access to the textBox1 field, if it is required, because you are accessing it from the another thread (DoWork is executed in another Thread, but RunWorkerCompleted is in the UI thread). Therefore, complete code should be like this:

```
public static void doit(string a, string b)
{
    Form1 F1 = Application.openForms[0] as Form1;
    if(F1.InvokeRequired)
        F1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { F1.Text = a + b; });
    else
        F1.Text = a + b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i need a little bit help.

I run the background worker in a other c# Project.
the Problem is that this Project have a huge comboBoxes and text boxes the backgroundworker accessed in runtime.

So how i can access the Controls in GUI without put them all to a,

textbox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoke(()............})); Option...